# Wifi to be like pc?

Tags: unix, networking, routes, wifi, openwrt

Is it possible to make wifi router with openWRT to be like an computer ? I mean, that admin of network (where wifi is connected) couldn't recognize, that any wifi router is connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Increase TTL of forwarded packets using iptables.

2) Change WAN MAC to MAC of PC's copper NIC.

3) Do not publish services on WAN.

Comment: This is described in http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/secure.access (follow dropbear and uhttpd links)